# How to find this element from xPath

Tags: selenium, xpath

Here is the page source:

```
<div id="accounts-menu" class="yui3-menu menu yui3-menu-horizontal menu-horizontal yui3-splitbuttonnav " role="menu">
<div class="yui3-menu-content" role="presentation" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_903">
  <ul class="accounts-menu first-of-type" role="presentation" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_902">


  <li class=" account-company-item-menu yui3-menuitem" role="presentation">

    <a class="yui3-menuitem-content" href="/account/company" title="" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_750">
      <div class="menu-label">Company</div>
    </a>
  </li>


  <li class="selected account-systems-management-menu yui3-menuitem account-selected" role="presentation" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_901">

    <a class="yui3-menuitem-content" href="/account/company/computers" title="Manage computer systems for Company" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_752">
      <div class="menu-label">Computers</div>
    </a>
  </li>



  <li class="account-support-menu yui3-menuitem" role="presentation" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_922">

    <a class="yui3-menuitem-content" href="http://support.canonical.com" title="Get support for Company" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_754">
      <div class="menu-label">Support</div>
    </a>
  </li>



  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically this one:

```
          <div class="menu-label">Computers</div>
```

I'd like to find the linked text "Computers" and click it with selenium. After digging around a lot of resources and tutorials about xPath online, still unable to locate the element :/

Managed to get something close:`//*[@title=\"Manage computer systems for Company\"]//*[text()='Computers'`, this will find an array contains this element, still not there yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can append a `[1]` to get the first matching node:

    `//*[@title="Manage computer systems for Company"]//*[text()='Computers'][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any of these below xpath.

**Explanation:** Use `class` attribute of `div` tag along with `text` method.

```
//div[@class='menu-label'][contains(text(), 'Computers')]
```

OR

**Explanation:** Use `text` method of `div` tag.

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Computers')]
```

OR

**Explanation:** Use `title` attribute of `a` tag. and move ahead with `div` tag.

```
//a[@title='Manage computer systems for Company']/div
```

OR

**Explanation:** Use `href` attribute of `a` tag. and move ahead with `div` tag.

```
//a[@href='/account/company/computers']/div
```

OR

**Explanation:** Use `id` attribute of `a` tag. and move ahead with `div` tag.

```
//a[@id='yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_752']/div
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need it to be related to the `<a>` with `title="Get support for Company"`then it should be something like:

```
//a[@title="Manage computer systems for Company"]/div[@class='menu-label']
```

if not, it is always better to query by id:

```
//li[@id="yui_3_18_1_1_1487717925042_901"]//div[@class='menu-label']
```

Answer (score 0):

Following **xpath** can be used to reach to the required control:

```
//a[@title='Manage computer systems for Company']/div[text()='Computers']
```